# Svn Commit failed. HTTP status 413 'Request Entity Too Large

Tags: svn, request, entity

When I try to commit files up to 100 kb (approximately) SVN server returns me the following error:

> svn: Unexpected HTTP status 413 'Request Entity Too Large' on '/svn/!svn/txr/17-v/SecurePack/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/pages/css/bootstrap.css'

I'm using Apache2 server on Ubuntu 15.
To avoid problems related to svn update limits i set a LimitXMLRequestBody 0 in my dav_svn.conf but the error persists:

```css
<Location /svn>
  DAV svn
  SVNPath /svn
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Subversion Repository"
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd
  LimitXMLRequestBody 0
  Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I think your question might be a better fit on http://superuser.com/ or http://serverfault.com/ as less about programming than about configuration. Have a look on their [help](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic) [pages](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) to find the best fit

Comment: In short: you forgot one additional directive `LimitRequestBody 0`

Comment: I solved using LimitRequestBody 0 instad of LimitXMLRequestBody 0.